# Pandas Dataframe pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy give KeyError when called get_group(chrLong) although chrLong exists in groups.keys()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, keyerror

There is a pandas dataframe groupby object e.g.: its name is chrBased_grouped

```
if chrLong in chrBased_grouped.groups.keys():
 #double check
 if chrLong in chrBased_grouped.groups:
   chrBased_df = chrBased_grouped.get_group(chrLong)
```

gives KeyError when key exists but the chrBased_df  to be returned is an empty dataframe.

How to resolve this? Any idea?

Comment: can you provide a dataframe example and running code that outputs the error?

Comment: It is big data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found such a solution:

```
   for name, chrBased_df in chrBased_grouped:
        if (chrLong==name) and (chrBased_df is not None) and  (not chrBased_df.empty):
            process(chrBased_df)
```

In this way, I do not get KeyError when   chrBased_df  is empty dataframe.